# How much sunlight do elephant ears need?

Tags: sunlight

These elephant ears/taro (Colocasia esculenta) have put out leaves, three plants in all. Two of them have only one small leaf and the third one has two big leaves and two small ones. These have been kept in complete shade all the time. Should I place these in sunlight? If so, then for how long?

My location is New Delhi, temperatures 25~41 degree celsius around.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They only need bright, indirect sunlight. Never put them in direct sunlight for too long. The leave's can be burned

Answer (score 0):

They do not need direct sun , but with a good water supply they will grow faster with some sun. Those around my pond require thinning a couple times a year and they get no direct sun.